# Subprocess.check_output with grep: exit-status 2

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I've used subprocess before without any problems, for some reason when I try it with grep:

```
grepOut = subprocess.check_output("grep 'hello' tmp", shell=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['grep', "'hello'", 'tmp']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I don't get any errors by typing the command directly in a terminal.

EDIT: see clemej's answer for the explanation

Comment: Exit status 1 != exit status 2.  Exit status 1 means it didn't find the string.  Exit status 2 means an error.

Comment: @clemej My apologies, realized that as you posted the comment, giving you the answer!

Comment: do not change the code in your question. Now the error message is no longer corresponds to the code. One of the issues in your code is (as [@clemej pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23420348/4279)) the usage of a list argument together with `shell=True` that changes the meaning of the arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong arguments when shell=True.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

When you're using shell=True, the first argument isn't a list of string arguments, but the command as a string:

```
grepOut = subprocess.check_output("grep 'hello' tmp", shell=True)
```

should work.

You only need to use the list form when not specifying shell=True, so alternatively:

```
grepOut = subprocess.check_output(['grep', "'hello'", 'tmp'])
```

should also work.

Comment: sorry I had actually tried that, forgot to mention. **grepOut = subprocess.check_output("grep 'hello' tmp", shell=True)** gives me the same error. No other terminal commands give me this problem though.

Comment: edited the main question to reflect that I still have that problem using your proposed solution

Comment: Are you positive? because when i cut-n-paste your tests into my python2.7 install (after creating a file tmp by 'echo "hello" > tmp'), subprocess.check_output("grep 'hello' tmp", shell=True) works, but the original way does not.

Comment: You've changed the question, and now you're getting exit status 1.  That's very different.  That means it couldnt' find the string hello in the file.

Comment: [do not use quotes inside quotes when the command is run without shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23468136/4279)

Comment: I don't have quotes inside my command. I have this error with and without Shell=true, with string and with array. From command line it works.
`grep -R -Hn -I -A2 -B50 search_phrase * -s`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to read from the standard error stream to see what is going wrong. You could also just use call() and read the output from stdout, thereby ignoring the return code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is: `out = subprocess.check_output(['grep', 'hello', 'tmp'])`.

Note: no `shell=True`, no quotes inside quotes.

`grep` returns exit status 2 if an error happens. In this case the original code in your question was equivalent to calling `grep` without any arguments that is incorrect: grep expects a pattern as a mandatory argument.